# Updating some columns which are not used in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I got two tables. Lets call one `items`. The columns in it are some unique id, the position and its old position.
If it has an old position its currently moving from `position_old` to `position`. If it has a `-` in position old
its not moving. There can be multiple items on each position.

The second table (`position`) is for the positions. The columns in it are an unique id and a status.

I need to update all rows in the position table which have status 100 and have no item which is moving to it
(`position = position_id AND position_old != '-'`) and no item moving from it (`position_old = position_id`).

```
+---------+----------+--------------+
| item_id | position | position_old |
+---------+----------+--------------+
|       1 | 0001     | -            |
|       2 | 0001     | 0002         |
+---------+----------+--------------+

+-------------+--------+
| position_id | status |
+-------------+--------+
| 0001        |      0 |
| 0002        |    100 |
+-------------+--------+
```

I got some solution but I don't think it will be the best one:

```
UPDATE Position
SET    status = 0
WHERE  status = 100
AND    position_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT position_old FROM Items WHERE position_old != '-'
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT position FROM Items WHERE position_old != '-'
)
```

So is there are better way to do that? Just for the Info
its a Oracle 11.2.0.4 database and if you suggest something with joins it should be the crappy old syntax as far as everyone
here is working with it and not willing to learn the newer standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think more efficient will be:

```
UPDATE Position out_pos
SET    status = 0
WHERE  status = 100
AND  not exists (
SELECT 1  FROM Items sub_pos WHERE 
 sub_pos.position_old != '-' and 
 ( 
  sub_pos.position = out_pos.position_id 
  OR 
  sub_pos.position_old = out_pos.position_id
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is correct, but I would prefer to write it with "not exists" to match the natural language form:

```
UPDATE Position
SET    status = 0
WHERE
  -- which have status 100:
  status = 100
  AND
  -- have no item which is moving to it:
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM items WHERE position = position_id AND position_old <> '-')
  AND
  -- no item moving from it:
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM items WHERE position_old = position_id)
```

As for efficiency, there's no substitute for executing the statement and looking at the execution plan. Oracle will happily rewrite "EXISTS" to "IN" and so on, based on existence of indices, the cardinality of your tables and selectivity of conditions (and lots more...).

It seems likely that an index on `items` with the columns `position_old, position` (in that order) would be helpful.